# Switch Selection Bar Vertical

Tags: python, cursor

I am working on my first game in Python that is similar to Bejeweled with a few twists.  The game runs fine, but I am trying to make a change that is just not working.

Right now the game has a "selection bar" called cursor.  Players move this bar left, right, up, and down between two shapes.  When they want to swap the shapes places, they simply press the space bar and the images swap locations.  While this format works well enough, I want the cursor to be able to switch between being horizontal and vertical.  Right now the bar is only horizontal which makes swapping shapes from above or below impossible.

Here is the full code:

```
import pygame, random, time, sys
from pygame.locals import *
import itertools
import os

WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)

SHAPE_WIDTH = 64                # Width of each shape (pixels).
SHAPE_HEIGHT = 64               # Height of each shape (pixels).
PUZZLE_COLUMNS = 10              # Number of columns on the board.
PUZZLE_ROWS = 11                # Number of rows on the board.
MARGIN = 118                     # Margin around the board (pixels).
WINDOW_WIDTH = PUZZLE_COLUMNS * SHAPE_WIDTH + 2 * MARGIN + 485
WINDOW_HEIGHT = PUZZLE_ROWS * SHAPE_HEIGHT + 2 * MARGIN - 150
FONT_SIZE = 60
TEXT_OFFSET = MARGIN + 950

# Map from number of matches to points scored.
MINIMUM_MATCH = 4
EXTRA_LENGTH_POINTS = .1
RANDOM_POINTS = .3
DELAY_PENALTY_SECONDS = 1
DELAY_PENALTY_POINTS = 0

FPS = 30
EXPLOSION_SPEED = 15            # In frames per second.
SPIN_SPEED = 15
REFILL_SPEED = 10               # In cells per second.

VERTICAL = False

class Cell(object):
"""
A cell on the board, with properties:
 `image` -- a `Surface` object containing the sprite to draw here.
 `offset` -- vertical offset in pixels for drawing this cell.
"""
def __init__(self, image):
    self.offset = 0.0
    self.image = image

def tick(self, dt):
    self.offset = max(0.0, self.offset - dt * REFILL_SPEED)

class Board(object):
"""
A rectangular board of cells, with properties:
`w` -- width in cells.
`h` -- height in cells.
`size` -- total number of cells.
`board` -- list of cells.
`matches` -- list of matches, each being a list of exploding cells.
`refill` -- list of cells that are moving up to refill the board.
`score` -- score due to chain reactions.
"""
def __init__(self, width, height):
    self.explosion = [pygame.image.load('images/explosion{}.png'.format(i))
                      for i in range(1, 7)]
    self.spin = [pygame.image.load('images/powerframe{}.png'.format(i))
                  for i in range (1, 12)]
    self.image_color = {}
    self.shapes = []
    self.rareshapes = []

    colors = 'red blue yellow'
    letters = 'acgtu'

    for c in colors.split():
        im = pygame.image.load('images/{}.png'.format(c))
        self.shapes.append(im)
        self.image_color[im] = c
        for l in letters:
            im = pygame.image.load('rareimages/{}{}.png'.format(c, l))
            self.rareshapes.append(im)
            self.image_color[im] = l

    self.background = pygame.image.load("images/bg.png")
    self.blank = pygame.image.load("images/blank.png")
    self.x = pygame.image.load("images/x.png")
    self.w = width
    self.h = height
    self.size = width * height
    self.board = [Cell(self.blank) for _ in range(self.size)]
    self.matches = []
    self.refill = []
    self.score = 0.0
    self.spin_time = 15


def randomize(self):
    """
    Replace the entire board with fresh shapes.
    """
    rareshapecount = 0
    for i in range(self.size):
        if rareshapecount <= 8:
            self.board[i] = Cell (random.choice(self.shapes))
            rareshapecount = rareshapecount + 1

        elif rareshapecount == 9:
            self.board[i] = Cell (random.choice(self.rareshapes))
            rareshapecount = rareshapecount + 1

        elif rareshapecount <=22:
            self.board[i] = Cell(random.choice(self.shapes))
            rareshapecount = rareshapecount + 1

        elif rareshapecount == 23:
            self.board[i] = Cell(random.choice(self.rareshapes))
            rareshapecount = rareshapecount + 1

        elif rareshapecount <= 26:
            self.board[i] = Cell (random.choice(self.shapes))
            rareshapecount = rareshapecount + 1

        elif rareshapecount == 27:
            self.board[i] = Cell (random.choice(self.rareshapes))
            rareshapecount = rareshapecount + 1

        elif rareshapecount <= 40:
            self.board[i] = Cell (random.choice(self.shapes))
            rareshapecount = rareshapecount + 1

        elif rareshapecount == 41:
            self.board[i] = Cell (random.choice(self.rareshapes))
            rareshapecount = rareshapecount + 1

        elif rareshapecount <= 45:
            self.board[i] = Cell (random.choice(self.shapes))
            rareshapecount = rareshapecount + 1

        elif rareshapecount == 46:
            self.board[i] = Cell (random.choice(self.rareshapes))
            rareshapecount = rareshapecount + 1

        elif rareshapecount <= 57:
            self.board[i] = Cell (random.choice(self.shapes))
            rareshapecount = rareshapecount + 1

        elif rareshapecount <= 59:
            self.board[i] = Cell (random.choice(self.rareshapes))
            rareshapecount = rareshapecount + 1

        elif rareshapecount <= 70:
            self.board[i] = Cell (random.choice(self.shapes))
            rareshapecount = rareshapecount + 1

        elif rareshapecount == 71:
            self.board[i] = Cell (random.choice(self.rareshapes))
            rareshapecount = rareshapecount + 1

        elif rareshapecount <= 200:
            self.board[i] = Cell (random.choice(self.shapes))
            rareshapecount = rareshapecount + 1



def pos(self, i, j):
    """
    Return the index of the cell at position (i, j).
    """
    assert(0 <= i < self.w)
    assert(0 <= j < self.h)
    return j * self.w + i

def busy(self):
    """
    Return `True` if the board is busy animating an explosion or a
    refill and so no further swaps should be permitted.
    """
    return self.refill or self.matches

def tick(self, dt):
    """
    Advance the board by `dt` seconds: move rising blocks (if
    any); otherwise animate explosions for the matches (if any);
    otherwise check for matches.
    """
    if self.refill:
        for c in self.refill:
            c.tick(dt)
        self.refill = [c for c in self.refill if c.offset > 0]
        if self.refill:
            return
    elif self.matches:
        self.explosion_time += dt
        f = int(self.explosion_time * EXPLOSION_SPEED)
        if f < len(self.explosion):
            self.update_matches(self.explosion[f])
            return
        self.update_matches(self.blank)
        self.refill = list(self.refill_columns())
    self.explosion_time = 0
    self.matches = self.find_matches()

def draw(self, display):
    """
    Draw the board on the pygame surface `display`.
    """
    display.blit(self.background, (0, 0))
    for i, c in enumerate(self.board):
        display.blit(c.image,
                     (MARGIN + SHAPE_WIDTH * (i % self.w),
                      MARGIN + SHAPE_HEIGHT * (i // self.w - c.offset) - 68))
    display.blit(self.x, (995, 735))
    display.blit(self.x, (1112, 735))
    display.blit(self.x, (1228, 735))

def swap(self, cursor):
    """
    Swap the two board cells covered by `cursor` and update the
    matches.
    """
    i = self.pos(*cursor)
    b = self.board
    b[i], b[i+1] = b[i+1], b[i]
    self.matches = self.find_matches()


def find_matches(self):
    """
    Search for matches (lines of cells with identical images) and
    return a list of them, each match being represented as a list
    of board positions.
    """
    def lines():
        for j in range(self.h):
            yield range(j * self.w, (j + 1) * self.w)
        for i in range(self.w):
            yield range(i, self.size, self.w)
    def key(i):
        return self.image_color.get(self.board[i].image)
    def matches():
        for line in lines():
            for _, group in itertools.groupby(line, key):
                match = list(group)
                if len(match) >= MINIMUM_MATCH:
                    yield match
                    self.score = self.score + 1
    return list(matches())

def update_matches(self, image):
    """
    Replace all the cells in any of the matches with `image`.
    """
    for match in self.matches:
        for position in match:
            self.board[position].image = image

def refill_columns(self):
    """
    Move cells downwards in columns to fill blank cells, and
    create new cells as necessary so that each column is full. Set
    appropriate offsets for the cells to animate into place.
    """
    for i in range(self.w):
        target = self.size - i - 1
        for pos in range(target, -1, -self.w):
            if self.board[pos].image != self.blank:
                c = self.board[target]
                c.image = self.board[pos].image
                c.offset = (target - pos) // self.w
                target -= self.w
                yield c
        offset = 1 + (target - pos) // self.w
        for pos in range(target, -1, -self.w):
            c = self.board[pos]
            c.image = random.choice(self.shapes)
            c.offset = offset
            yield c

class Game(object):
"""
The state of the game, with properties:
`clock` -- the pygame clock.
`display` -- the window to draw into.
`font` -- a font for drawing the score.
`board` -- the board of cells.
`cursor` -- the current position of the (left half of) the cursor.
`score` -- the player's score.
`last_swap_ticks` -- 
`swap_time` -- time since last swap (in seconds).
"""
def __init__(self):
    pygame.init()
    pygame.display.set_caption("Nucleotide")
    self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    self.display = pygame.display.set_mode((WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT),
                                           DOUBLEBUF)
    self.board = Board(PUZZLE_COLUMNS, PUZZLE_ROWS)
    self.font = pygame.font.Font(None, FONT_SIZE)

def start(self):
    """
    Start a new game with a random board.
    """
    self.board.randomize()
    self.cursor = [0, 0]
    self.cursor2 = [0, 0]
    self.score = 0.0
    self.swap_time = 10

def quit(self):
    """
    Quit the game and exit the program.
    """
    pygame.quit()
    sys.exit()

def play(self):
    """
    Play a game: repeatedly tick, draw and respond to input until
    the QUIT event is received.
    """
    self.start()
    while True:
        self.draw()
        dt = min(self.clock.tick(FPS) / 1000.0, 1.0 / FPS)
        self.swap_time -= dt
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == KEYUP:
                self.input(event.key)
            elif event.type == QUIT:
                self.quit()
            elif self.swap_time == 0.0:
                self.quit()
        self.board.tick(dt)

def input(self, key):
    """
    Respond to the player pressing `key`.
    """
    if key == K_q:
        self.quit()
    elif key == K_f:
        if VERTICAL == False:
            VERTICAL = True
        elif VERTICAL == True:
            VERTICAL = False
    elif key == K_RIGHT and self.cursor[0] < self.board.w - 2:
        self.cursor[0] += 1
    elif key == K_LEFT and self.cursor[0] > 0:
        self.cursor[0] -= 1
    elif key == K_DOWN and self.cursor[1] < self.board.h - 1:
        self.cursor[1] += 1
    elif key == K_UP and self.cursor[1] > 0:
        self.cursor[1] -= 1
    elif key == K_SPACE and not self.board.busy():
        self.swap()

def swap(self):
    """
    Swap the two cells under the cursor and update the player's score.
    """
    swap_penalties = int(self.swap_time / DELAY_PENALTY_SECONDS)
    self.swap_time = 1
    self.board.swap(self.cursor)

def draw(self):
    self.board.draw(self.display)
    self.draw_score()
    self.draw_time()
    if VERTICAL == False:
        self.draw_cursor()
    elif VERTICAL == True:
        self.draw_cursor2()
    pygame.display.update()

def draw_time(self):
    s = int(self.swap_time)
    text = self.font.render('{}:{:02}'.format(s / 60, s % 60),
                            True, BLACK)
    self.display.blit(text, (TEXT_OFFSET, WINDOW_HEIGHT - 170))

def draw_score(self):
    total_score = self.score

def draw_cursor(self):
    topLeft = (MARGIN + self.cursor[0] * SHAPE_WIDTH,
            MARGIN + self.cursor[1] * SHAPE_HEIGHT - 68)
    topRight = (topLeft[0] + SHAPE_WIDTH * 2, topLeft[1])
    bottomLeft = (topLeft[0], topLeft[1] + SHAPE_HEIGHT)
    bottomRight = (topRight[0], topRight[1] + SHAPE_HEIGHT)
    pygame.draw.lines(self.display, WHITE, True,
            [topLeft, topRight, bottomRight, bottomLeft], 3)

def draw_cursor2(self):
      topLeft = (MARGIN + self.cursor[0] * SHAPE_WIDTH,
               MARGIN + self.cursor[1] * SHAPE_HEIGHT - 68)
      topRight = (topLeft[0] + SHAPE_WIDTH, topLeft[1])
      bottomLeft = (topLeft[0], topLeft[1] + SHAPE_HEIGHT * 2)
      bottomRight = (topRight[0], topRight[1] + SHAPE_HEIGHT * 2)
      pygame.draw.lines(self.display, WHITE, True,
                  [topLeft, topRight, bottomRight, bottomLeft], 3)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Game().play()
```

EDIT:

Rather than start a new post, I decided to just edit this one since it is about the same issue.  I have made some more progress on it and changed everything to True/False like suggested.  However, I am running into an "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'VERTICAL' referenced before assignment" error whenever you press "F" to switch the bar.  Another issue that I have been trying to solve is once the bar is switched, it doesn't swap the pieces the correct direction.  If the bar is vertical, it still swaps the tiles horizontally.  The code before the edit has been changed and now includes the WHOLE game.

Any ideas on the error?  If I set VERTICAL to True, the bar switches so the drawing code is correct, so I assume it has to do with the key pressing.  Also, any ideas on the swapping to make it swap them vertical?

Comment: I have managed to change the cursor itself so it can be vertical as well as horizontal.  Created VERTICAL and assigned it 0.  When the player presses a CTRL, it should change it to 1 and then the cursor will be vertical.  However, its not switching.  I can manually assign 1 to VERTICAL so it starts the game vertical, but pressing CTRL doesn't switch it back and forth.  Also ran into another issue with the swapping.  See the edit's above.

Comment: Looks to me like you might be changing VERTICAL to 1 before you get to the code which does the actual swapping. Logically, it would make sense to call the function that does the swap and then change the value of VERTICAL. Also, I recommend turning VERTICAL into a Boolean (True/False), as that usually makes more sense when reading code.